# Powershell 2.0 generates nulls between characters

Tags: null, powershell-2.0

With powershell 2.0:

```
write-output "abcd" >> mytext.txt
```

returns:

> a nul b nul c nul d nul

od -c shows the nul as a true binary zero, `\0` , or:  `a \0 b \0 c \0 d \0` (and `\r \0 \n \0`).

I am trying to generate some SQL, so I don't think this will do.  Any ideas of what's going on and how to use write-output to just get the specified characters?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is because write-output defaults to UTF-16 text encoding, which is 2 bytes per character. When you are dealing with text that fits into the ASCII codepage range, the 2nd byte of each character will be zero.

This is controlled by the `$OutputEncoding` global variable, so you could set that to ASCII.

Another option is to use the cmdlet Out-File, which has an explicit encoding parameter. I would suggest you use this instead of output redirection, because that saves you from changing your environment globally (by setting the global preference variable `$OutputEncoding`)

Using Out-File, and setting encoding to be ASCII, your example would look like this:

```
"abcd" | out-file "mytext.txt" -Encoding ASCII
```

Do be aware that not all characters are representable in ASCII, and you should determine whether this is an appropiate encoding for your purpose. Personally I would typically go for UTF-8, since it is ASCII equivalent when characters fall in the ASCII range from 0-127, but also handles international characters. [Obligatory link about text encoding](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Comment: Thanks for your speedy and complete response.  In the 21st century one should never expect ASCII - as is so well addresses by the Joel article cited above!

Comment: Just for anyone who views this as search output in the future, out-file supports a -append flag, so what I would use is:        "abcd" | out-file "mytext.txt" -Encoding ASCII -append

Answer (score 4):

Powershell works in 16 bit unicode by default, and however you're reading the file is likely in an 8 bit format. You could interpret the sql in an application that can read UTF16, or, because >> is syntactic sugar for the out-file cmdlet, you can do the following instead:

```
write-output "abcd" | out-file -path mytext.txt -Encoding "UTF8" -Append
```

Comment: Thanks for your speedy response - the answer I needed, but I can only mark one as accepted.