# Python search and replace in CSV iteratively by line

Tags: python, csv

I'm looking to extend the Python solution found here:
[PowerShell is slow (much slower than Python) in large Search/Replace operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9724521/powershell-is-slow-much-slower-than-python-in-large-search-replace-operation)

To replace string across CSV files I use:
`findReplace("c:/temp/csv", "Search String", "Replace String", "*.csv")`

What I'd like to be able to do is have "Search" and "Replace" be a list of terms. I cannot use re as the term is unknown prior to finding it manually.  However, since the CSV files have the same structure and may have the same string values finding the term once is sufficient to automate the process.

Any insight on best approach would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "*I cannot use re as the term is unknown prior to finding it manually*" - If you don't know what you're searching for, you're better of search and replacing in a decent text editor, once you've identified something that needs replacing while you've got the file open, surely?

Comment: @JonClements correct, I'm using a text editor for the initial find of invalid character data and then using the Python script to do the heavy work of finding all instances of that term to replace with valid characters.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned lists, so I'm guessing you have two lists like this:

```
findlist = ['hey', 'hello', 'hi']
replacelist = ['bye', 'see ya', 'brb']
```

You can load them into a dictionary with this:

```
rep = dict(zip(findlist, replacelist))
```

Then the function can be written:

```
for item in findlist:
    findReplace("c:/temp/csv", item, rep[item], "*.csv")
```

I'm definitely a StackOverflow newbie, but it would help if you provided sample inputs and the desired outputs. Otherwise we'll just guess, and the answer may not be what you want.

Comment: good point, I basically said lists as am guessing about best solutions here.  The search and replace arguments find a single term within a line of text in a csv file and replace it.  However, I have many strings to test per line, if there is a hit, replace with the appropriate replacement.