# Speed issue on -match operation for large text file

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have a data foundation of 36 .log-Files, which I need to pre process in order to load them into a pandas data frame for data visualization within python frameworks.

To provide an example of a single line within one of the .log-Files:

```
[16:24:42]: Downloaded 0 Z_SYSTEM_FM traces from DEH, clients (282) from 00:00:00,000 to 00:00:00,000
```

From several sources and posts on here I figure out the following code to be the best performing one:

```
foreach ($f in $files){

    $date = $f.BaseName.Substring(22,8)

    ((Get-Content $f) -match "^.*\bDownloaded\b.*$") -replace "[[]", "" -replace "]:\s", " " 
    -replace "Downloaded " -replace "Traces from " -replace ",.*" -replace "$", " $date" 
    | add-content CleanedLogs.txt

}
```

Variable `$date` is containing the date, the respective .log-file is logging.

I am not able to change the input text data. I tried to read in the 1,55GB using -raw, but I couldn't manage to split up the resulting single string after processing all operations.
Additionally I tried to use more regex expression, but there was no reduction of the total runtime. Maybe there is a way to use grep for this operations?

Maybe someone has a genious tweak to speed up this operation. At the moment this operation takes up close to 20 minutes to compute. Thank you very much!

Comment: Is there a solid single regex that is including all -match and -replace oeprations? I tried it for 2 hours, but couldn't figure out how to do it. I will try your suggestions for read and write!

Comment: Re regexes: probably not; you need at least 1 `-match` to select only lines of interest, and then start replacing (`-replace` doesn't filter, it passes lines that don't match through). You can at least consolidate all those `-replace` operations that _remove_ strings into one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to better performance is:

- Avoid use of the pipeline and cmdlets, in particular for file I/O (`Get-Content`, `Add-Content`)

  - Use the [`System.IO.File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file) type's methods instead.
- Avoid looping in PowerShell code.

  - Instead, chain array-aware operators such as `-match` and `-replace` - which you're already doing.
  - Consolidate your regexes to make fewer `-replace` calls.
  - Use *precompiled* regexes.

To put it all together:

```
# Create precompiled regexes.
# Note: As written, they make the matching that -replace performs
#       case-*sensitive* (and culture-sensitive), 
#       which speeds things up slightly.
#       If you need case-*insensitive* matching, use option argument
#       'Compiled, IgnoreCase' instead.
$reMatch    = New-Object regex '\bDownloaded\b', 'Compiled'
$reReplace1 = New-Object regex 'Downloaded |Traces from |\[', 'Compiled'
$reReplace2 = New-Object regex '\]:\s', 'Compiled'
$reReplace3 = New-Object regex ',.*', 'Compiled'

# The platform-appropriate newline sequence.
$nl = [Environment]::NewLine

foreach ($f in $files) {

  $date = $f.BaseName.Substring(22,8)

  # Read all lines into an array, filter and replace, then join the
  # resulting lines with newlines and append the resulting single string
  # to the log file.
  [IO.File]::AppendAllText($PWD.ProviderPath + '/CleanedLogs.txt',
    ([IO.File]::ReadAllLines($f.FullName) -match
      $reMatch -replace 
        $reReplace1 -replace 
          $reReplace2, ' ' -replace 
            $reReplace3, " $date" -join 
              $nl) + $nl
  )

}
```

Note that each file must fit into memory as a whole as an array of lines, plus a proportion of it (both as an array and as a single, multi-line string) whose size depends on how many lines are filtered in.

Comment: I've noticed massive improvements with system.IO.file methods. Does precompiling regex make similar gains? If the case sensitivity is causing it to slow, could a -creplace substitute for precompiling?

Comment: @Blaisem, I'm not sure  how much you gain by precompiling; a certain number regexes are cached by default, both by PowerShell (1000, fixed) and .NET (15, configurable), but such automatically cached ones use a _higher-level_ compiled representation than explicit precompiling, which creates MSIL that the JITTer can compile to native code. With letter-heavy regexes, using `-creplace` probably does help - again, not sure how much.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem in the past. Long story short, using .NET directly is way faster while using large type of files. You can learn more by reading [performance considerations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/performance-tuning/powershell/script-authoring-considerations).

The fastest way probably would be by using `IO.FileStream`. For example:

```
$File = "C:\Path_To_File\Logs.txt"
$FileToSave = "C:\Path_To_File\result.txt"
$Stream = New-Object -TypeName IO.FileStream -ArgumentList ($File), ([System.IO.FileMode]::Open), ([System.IO.FileAccess]::Read), ([System.IO.FileShare]::ReadWrite)
$Reader = New-Object -TypeName System.IO.StreamReader -ArgumentList ($Stream, [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII, $true)
$Writer = New-Object -TypeName System.IO.StreamWriter -ArgumentList ($FileToSave)
while (!$Reader.EndOfStream)
{
    $Box = $Reader.ReadLine()
    if($Box -match "^.*\bDownloaded\b.*$")
    {
        $ReplaceLine = $Box -replace "1", "1234" -replace "[[]", ""
        $Writer.WriteLine($ReplaceLine)
    }
}
$Reader.Close()
$Writer.Close()
$Stream.Close()
```

You should be able to edit the code above for your needs pretty easily. For getting list of files you can use [Get-ChildItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-6).

Also I advice you to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9724521/powershell-is-slow-much-slower-than-python-in-large-search-replace-operation/46694330) stackoverflow post.

Comment: I get an error on ```$Box = $Reader.ReadLine()```: ```It is not possible to call a method for an expression that is NULL
In C:\Users\jmoecke\PycharmProjects\TraceDashboardV3\Stackoverflow2.ps1:9 Characters:9
+         $Box = $Reader.ReadLine()
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull```. Do you have an idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Code is working fine for me. Try `$Reader` without `Encoding` parameter, like: `$Reader = New-Object -TypeName System.IO.StreamReader -ArgumentList $Stream`. What changes did you make in your code?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will speed up things for you:

```
$outFile = Join-Path -Path $PSScriptRoot -ChildPath 'CleanedLogs.txt'
$files   = Get-ChildItem -Path '<YOUR ROOTFOLDER>' -Filter '*.txt' -File
foreach ($f in $files){
    $date = $f.BaseName.Substring(22,8)
    [string[]]$lines = ([System.IO.File]::ReadAllLines($f.FullName) | Where-Object {$_ -match '^.*\bDownloaded\b.*$'} | ForEach-Object {
        ($_ -replace '\[|Downloaded|Traces from|,.*', '' -replace ']:\s', ' ' -replace '\s+', ' ') + " $date"
    })
    [System.IO.File]::AppendAllLines($outFile, $lines)
}
```