# Get Unique records from large files quickly

Tags: powershell

I have big files (at least 20 MB each) where i need to look for string `M(\d{10})`

Below is the script I am using:

```
Get-Content -Path Test.log | %{ [Regex]::Matches($_, "M(\d{10})") } | %{ $_.Value } | select -Unique
```

This is taking good time and more CPU, please suggest how to get the results with lower CPU usage/quicker.

Comment: Probably You'd  need to use .net methods to be efficient , have a look here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439210/how-can-i-make-this-powershell-script-parse-large-files-faster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply measure yourself ( to minimize cache effect differences the first is repeated):

```
Measure-Command {Get-Content -Path Test.log | %{ [Regex]::Matches($_, "M(\d{10})") } | %{ $_.Value } | select -Unique}

Measure-Command {Get-Content -Path Test.log | %{ [Regex]::Matches($_, "M(\d{10})") } | %{ $_.Value } | select -Unique}

Measure-Command {sls -Path Test.log  "M(\d{10})"  | %{ $_.Matches.Groups[1].Value } | select -Unique}
```

Comment: This is working good and fast:

           Measure-Command {sls -Path Test.log  "M(\d{10})"  | %{ $_.Matches.Groups[0].Value } | select -Unique}

Thank you LotPings

Answer (score 1):

Using the *pipeline* is (potentially) *memory-efficient*, but *slow*.

To speed up processing:

- *avoid* the pipeline, but that is only an option if your data *fits into memory as a whole* - which shouldn't be a problem with 20 MB files.
- separately, use .NET framework types and their methods directly, which is usually faster than using *cmdlets*.

Applying these insights to your scenario (PSv3+ syntax):

```
[regex]::Matches(
   [IO.File]::ReadAllText($PWD.ProviderPath + '/Test.log'), 
   'M\d{10}'
).Value | Select-Object -Unique
```

Note that for convenience the pipeline is still used, with `Select-Object -Unique`, in order to get the unique occurrences, but the assumption is that the bulk of the processing - extracting the regex matches - is in the optimized part of the statement.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use multiple times `Foreach-Object` but instead use `Select-String`:

```
(Get-Content -Path Test.log | Select-String "(?<=M)\d{10}").Matches.Value | select -Unique
```

Comment: Wouldn't that ouput the whole line with the match not just the capture group?

Comment: @LotPings, you are right, I have changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: Another thing that can speed up the is using -ReadCount 0 on Get-Content. This will read the hole file at ones instead of 1 line at the time.