# Apache Ignite 2.7: ODBC Linux - Bad data returned

Tags: .net-core, odbc, ignite

I am testing out the Apache Ignite 2.7 Linux ODBC Driver, and it's not working correctly for some reason.

When I run a SQL statement, like `SELECT Id FROM MyTable`, the value is "garbled" returning a value like `8\00\05\07\09\0d\09\08\0-\0` for the the `Id` column. It's similar to the value I expect, though, which is `80579d98-9010-4610-b12e-ed33ed7d3c62`. I don't know if those are ASCII null characters (`\0`), or what, but something isn't right and I can't figure it out.

[image]

When I use the SQLLine tool, the values are not "garbled". I also installed the Windows ODBC driver, and that worked fine, but I need the Linux ODBC Driver.

[image]

I built the driver with the following libraries:

```
gcc 6.3.0 20170516 (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1)
GNU Make 4.1
libtoolize 2.4.6
aclocal 1.15
autoheader 2.69
automake 1.15
autoreconf 2.69
unixodbc 2.3.4-1
libssl 1.0.2r-1~deb9u1
```

Here's the contents of the ignite-odbc-install.ini:

```
# cat /src/apache-ignite-2.7.0-bin/platforms/cpp/odbc/install/ignite-odbc-install.ini
[Apache Ignite]
Description=Apache Ignite
Driver=/usr/local/lib/libignite-odbc.so
Setup=/usr/local/lib/libignite-odbc.so
DriverODBCVer=03.00
FileUsage=0
```

Here's the result of running odbcinst:

```
# odbcinst -i -d -f /src/apache-ignite-2.7.0-bin/platforms/cpp/odbc/install/ignite-odbc-install.ini
odbcinst: Driver installed. Usage count increased to 1.
    Target directory is /etc
```

Here's the contents of the /usr/local/lib folder:

```
# cd /usr/local/lib
# ls
libignite-binary-2.7.0.33575.so.0      libignite-common-2.7.0.33575.so.0      libignite-odbc-2.7.0.33575.so.0      libignite-thin-client-2.7.0.33575.so.0
libignite-binary-2.7.0.33575.so.0.0.0  libignite-common-2.7.0.33575.so.0.0.0  libignite-odbc-2.7.0.33575.so.0.0.0  libignite-thin-client-2.7.0.33575.so.0.0.0
libignite-binary.a                     libignite-common.a                     libignite-odbc.a                     libignite-thin-client.a
libignite-binary.la                    libignite-common.la                    libignite-odbc.la                    libignite-thin-client.la
libignite-binary.so                    libignite-common.so                    libignite-odbc.so                    libignite-thin-client.so
```

Here's the result from the ldd command:

```
# ldd /usr/local/lib/libignite-odbc.so
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fffa46d0000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f18d554c000)
        libignite-binary-2.7.0.33575.so.0 => /usr/local/lib/libignite-binary-2.7.0.33575.so.0 (0x00007f18d531d000)
        libodbcinst.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbcinst.so.2 (0x00007f18d5108000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f18d4d86000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f18d4a82000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f18d46e3000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f18d44cc000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f18d59f8000)
        libignite-common-2.7.0.33575.so.0 => /usr/local/lib/libignite-common-2.7.0.33575.so.0 (0x00007f18d42b5000)
        libltdl.so.7 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libltdl.so.7 (0x00007f18d40ab000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f18d3e8e000)
```

### UPDATE 1

I ran this from a .Net Core 2.2 C# Console program, with only the System.Data.Odbc 4.5.0 NuGet reference in a Docker Linux Environment.

**IgniteGarbledDataReproducer.csproj**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.Odbc" Version="4.5.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

**Program.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Data.Odbc;

namespace IgniteGarbledDataReproducer {
    internal class Program {
        private static void Main(string[] args) {
            Console.WriteLine("START");

            var connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("IGNITE_CONNECTION_STRING");
            Console.WriteLine(connectionString);

            using (var conn = new OdbcConnection(connectionString)) {
                conn.Open();

                Console.WriteLine("Connection Opened");

                using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand()) {
                    cmd.CommandText = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS MyTable;";
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Table Dropped (if it existed)");

                using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand()) {
                    cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE MyTable (Id varchar(36) not null, FirstName varchar(255), LastName varchar(255), PRIMARY KEY (Id));";
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Table Created");

                using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand()) {
                    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO MyTable (Id) VALUES ('80579d98-9010-4610-b12e-ed33ed7d3c62');";
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Data Inserted");

                using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand()) {
                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Id FROM MyTable;";
                    using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
                        while (rdr.Read())
                            Console.WriteLine($"Id = '{rdr["Id"]}'");
                    }
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Data Returned");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("DONE");
        }
    }
}
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app

WORKDIR /src
# Install pre-requisites for building and installing Ignite ODBC Driver
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y gcc g++ make automake autotools-dev libtool m4 libssl1.0-dev unixodbc-dev unixodbc-bin unzip \
    && apt-get clean -y

# Download and unzip Ignite binary release
#ADD http://apache.mirrors.hoobly.com/ignite/2.7.0/apache-ignite-2.7.0-bin.zip /src/
COPY apache-ignite-2.7.0-bin.zip .
RUN unzip -q /src/apache-ignite-2.7.0-bin.zip \
    && rm /src/apache-ignite-2.7.0-bin.zip

# Build Ignite ODBC Driver
ARG IGNITE_HOME=/src/apache-ignite-2.7.0-bin
WORKDIR /src/apache-ignite-2.7.0-bin/platforms/cpp
RUN libtoolize \
    && aclocal \
    && autoheader \
    && automake --add-missing \
    && autoreconf \
    && ./configure --enable-odbc --disable-core --disable-node \
    && make \
    && make install

# Install Ignite ODBC Driver
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y unixodbc \
    && apt-get clean -y \
    && odbcinst -i -d -f /src/apache-ignite-2.7.0-bin/platforms/cpp/odbc/install/ignite-odbc-install.ini

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY IgniteGarbledDataReproducer/IgniteGarbledDataReproducer.csproj IgniteGarbledDataReproducer/
RUN dotnet restore IgniteGarbledDataReproducer/IgniteGarbledDataReproducer.csproj
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/IgniteGarbledDataReproducer
RUN dotnet build IgniteGarbledDataReproducer.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish IgniteGarbledDataReproducer.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "IgniteGarbledDataReproducer.dll"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  ignitegarbleddatareproducer:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}ignite-garbled-data-reproducer
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: IgniteGarbledDataReproducer/Dockerfile
```

**docker-compose-override.yml**

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  ignitegarbleddatareproducer:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - IGNITE_CONNECTION_STRING=DRIVER={Apache Ignite};ADDRESS=my-ignite-3e8b8cb9a4e192af.elb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:10800;SSL_MODE=disable;
```

**Build**

```
docker build . -t ignitegarbleddatareproducer -f IgniteGarbledDataReproducer/Dockerfile
```

**Execute**

```
PS C:\IgniteGarbledDataReproducer> docker-compose up
Starting ignitegarbleddatareproducer_ignitegarbleddatareproducer_1 ... done
Attaching to ignitegarbleddatareproducer_ignitegarbleddatareproducer_1
ignitegarbleddatareproducer_1  | START
ignitegarbleddatareproducer_1  | DRIVER={Apache Ignite};ADDRESS=my-ignite-3e8b8cb9a4e192af.elb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:10800;SSL_MODE=disable;
ignitegarbleddatareproducer_1  | Connection Opened
ignitegarbleddatareproducer_1  | DROP TABLE IF EXISTS MyTable;
ignitegarbleddatareproducer_1  | Table Dropped (if it existed)
ignitegarbleddatareproducer_1  | CREATE TABLE MyTable (Id varchar(36) not null, FirstName varchar(255), LastName varchar(255), PRIMARY KEY (Id));
ignitegarbleddatareproducer_1  | Table Created
ignitegarbleddatareproducer_1  | INSERT INTO MyTable (Id) VALUES ('80579d98-9010-4610-b12e-ed33ed7d3c62');
ignitegarbleddatareproducer_1  | Data Inserted
ignitegarbleddatareproducer_1  | SELECT Id FROM MyTable;
ignitegarbleddatareproducer_1  | Id = '8 0 5 7 9 d 9 8 - '
ignitegarbleddatareproducer_1  | Data Returned
ignitegarbleddatareproducer_1  | DONE
ignitegarbleddatareproducer_ignitegarbleddatareproducer_1 exited with code 0
```

### UPDATE 2

I turned [on ODBC logging](https://www.easysoft.com/support/kb/kb00945.html) by adding the following to `/src/apache-ignite-2.7.0-bin/platforms/cpp/odbc/install/ignite-odbc-install.ini` and you can get [the logs here](https://pastebin.com/R8q709uZ).

```
[ODBC]
Trace=yes
TraceFile=/logs/odbc.log
```

The end of the log after the `SELECT Id From MyTable;` statement is below for convenience.

```
[ODBC][1][1556564832.827181][SQLExecDirectW.c][177]
        Entry:
            Statement = 0xf27a80
            SQL = [SELECT Id FROM MyTable;][length = 23 (SQL_NTS)]
[ODBC][1][1556564832.847882][SQLExecDirectW.c][445]
        Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
[ODBC][1][1556564832.852889][SQLRowCount.c][173]
        Entry:
            Statement = 0xf27a80
            Row Count = 0x7ffd7da98f00
[ODBC][1][1556564832.856831][SQLRowCount.c][247]
        Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
            Row Count = 0x7ffd7da98f00 -> 0
[ODBC][1][1556564832.860335][SQLNumResultCols.c][156]
        Entry:
            Statement = 0xf27a80
            Column Count = 0x7ffd7da98f50
[ODBC][1][1556564832.864944][SQLNumResultCols.c][251]
        Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
            Count = 0x7ffd7da98f50 -> 1
[ODBC][1][1556564832.869909][SQLFetch.c][162]
        Entry:
            Statement = 0xf27a80
[ODBC][1][1556564832.884876][SQLFetch.c][351]
        Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
[ODBC][1][1556564832.894173][SQLColAttributeW.c][156]
        Entry:
            Statement = 0xf27a80
            Column Number = 1
            Field Identifier = SQL_DESC_NAME
            Character Attr = 0xf2e190
            Buffer Length = 4096
            String Length = 0x7ffd7da98f20
            Numeric Attribute = 0x7ffd7da98ee0
[ODBC][1][1556564832.898409][SQLColAttributeW.c][523]
        Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
[ODBC][1][1556564832.910800][SQLColAttributeW.c][156]
        Entry:
            Statement = 0xf27a80
            Column Number = 1
            Field Identifier = SQL_DESC_CONCISE_TYPE
            Character Attr = 0xf2e190
            Buffer Length = 4096
            String Length = 0x7ffd7da98f40
            Numeric Attribute = 0x7ffd7da98f00
[ODBC][1][1556564832.914551][SQLColAttributeW.c][523]
        Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
[ODBC][1][1556564832.925913][SQLGetData.c][237]
        Entry:
            Statement = 0xf27a80
            Column Number = 1
            Target Type = -8 SQL_WCHAR
            Buffer Length = 4094
            Target Value = 0xf2e190
            StrLen Or Ind = 0x7ffd7da98ee0
[ODBC][1][1556564832.929959][SQLGetData.c][534]
        Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]                
            Buffer = [8](unicode)                
            Strlen Or Ind = 0x7ffd7da98ee0 -> 36
[ODBC][1][1556564832.934835][SQLFetch.c][162]
        Entry:
            Statement = 0xf27a80
[ODBC][1][1556564832.938930][SQLFetch.c][351]
        Exit:[SQL_NO_DATA]
[ODBC][1][1556564832.943970][SQLMoreResults.c][162]
        Entry:
            Statement = 0xf27a80
[ODBC][1][1556564832.960311][SQLMoreResults.c][345]
        Exit:[SQL_NO_DATA]
[ODBC][1][1556564832.965960][SQLFreeStmt.c][144]
        Entry:
            Statement = 0xf27a80
            Option = 0
[ODBC][1][1556564832.970025][SQLFreeStmt.c][266]
        Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
[ODBC][1][1556564832.975135][SQLFreeHandle.c][381]
        Entry:
            Handle Type = 3
            Input Handle = 0xf27a80
[ODBC][1][1556564832.981240][SQLFreeHandle.c][494]
        Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
[ODBC][1][1556564832.991337][SQLDisconnect.c][208]
        Entry:
            Connection = 0xf0a6f0
[ODBC][1][1556564832.996778][SQLDisconnect.c][379]
        Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
[ODBC][1][1556564833.001505][SQLFreeHandle.c][284]
        Entry:
            Handle Type = 2
            Input Handle = 0xf0a6f0
[ODBC][1][1556564833.006038][SQLFreeHandle.c][333]
        Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
```

### UPDATE 3

I have a hunch that it might have something to do with UTF-16 due to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806305/powershell-2-0-generates-nulls-between-characters) where characters are separated with a `\0`.

Maybe something to do with the UNICODE setting in this line from the ODBC logs?

```
[ODBC][1][1556564832.214691][SQLDriverConnectW.c][290]
        Entry:
            Connection = 0xf0a6f0
            Window Hdl = (nil)
            Str In = [DRIVER={Apache Ignite};ADDRESS=my-ignite-3e8b8cb9a4e192af.elb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:10800;SSL_MODE=disable;][length = 115 (SQL_NTS)]
            Str Out = (nil)
            Str Out Max = 0
            Str Out Ptr = 0x7ffd7da98dd0
            Completion = 0
        UNICODE Using encoding ASCII 'ANSI_X3.4-1968' and UNICODE 'UCS-2LE'
```

### UPDATE 4

I found this [document from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) which said

> If the ASCII character encoding is not UTF-8, for example:
>
> `UNICODE Using encoding ASCII 'ISO8859-1' and UNICODE 'UCS-2LE'`   There
>   is more than one Driver Manager installed and your application is
>   using the wrong one, or the Driver Manager was not built correctly.

*I'm assuming my driver isn't built correctly.*

And [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-driver-manager?view=sql-server-2017) said to use `--enable-iconv --with-iconv-char-enc=UTF8 --with-iconv-ucode-enc=UTF16LE`.

### UPDATE 5

I also found this [git issue](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/25269) related to .Net Core, unixODBC, and UTF16.

### UPDATE 6

I tried adding `--enable-iconv --with-iconv-char-enc=UTF8 --with-iconv-ucode-enc=UTF16LE` when calling unixODBC's `configure`, which changed the ODBC connection to `UNICODE Using encoding ASCII 'UTF8' and UNICODE 'UTF16LE'`, but I got the same bad data back regardless. I also tried `--with-iconv-ucode-enc=UNICODE`, but no change.

This is how I changed my Dockerfile. I removed unixodbc from apt-get and added the following to my Dockerfile

```
ADD ftp://ftp.unixodbc.org/pub/unixODBC/unixODBC-2.3.7.tar.gz .
RUN gunzip unixODBC*.tar.gz && tar xvf unixODBC*.tar

WORKDIR /src/unixODBC-2.3.7
RUN ./configure --enable-gui=no --enable-drivers=no --enable-iconv --with-iconv-char-enc=UTF8 --with-iconv-ucode-enc=UTF16LE
RUN make && make install

ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib"
```

And this is what the odbc log looks like now:

```
[ODBC][7][1556723781.839804][SQLDriverConnectW.c][290]
        Entry:
            Connection = 0x1ddff70
            Window Hdl = (nil)
            Str In = [DRIVER={Apache Ignite};ADDRESS=my-ignite-3e8b8cb9a4e192af.elb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:10800;SSL_MODE=disable;][length = 115 (SQL_NTS)]
            Str Out = (nil)
            Str Out Max = 0
            Str Out Ptr = 0x7ffeca3331a0
            Completion = 0
        UNICODE Using encoding ASCII 'UTF8' and UNICODE 'UTF16LE'
```

### UPDATE 7

I connected via [isql](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-isql/) and got the correct response, but when I connected via iusql I got the "bad data" from my reproducer.

### UPDATE 8

Adding some odbc installation info:

```
root@4efdb5ed98b5:/app# odbc_config --cflags
-DHAVE_UNISTD_H -DHAVE_PWD_H -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H -DHAVE_LONG_LONG -DSIZEOF_LONG_INT=8 -I/usr/local/include
root@4efdb5ed98b5:/app# odbc_config --ulen
-DSIZEOF_SQLULEN=8
root@4efdb5ed98b5:/app# odbcinst -j
unixODBC 2.3.7
DRIVERS............: /usr/local/etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /usr/local/etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /usr/local/etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /root/.odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8
```

Comment: What's the type of Id column? And how do you retrieve data? Show the code, please.

Comment: @NellieDanielyan Sorry for the delay. I had to create a reproducer as my code base was too complex to post. Question was updated with code that reproduces the issue. My ignite behind that AWS address is not publicly accessible, so you won't be able to hit it. You'll need to provide your own instance of Ignite 2.7.0.

Comment: Try `rdr.GetString(GetOrdinal("Id"))` instead of `rdr["Id"]`

Comment: @NellieDanielyan I have tried that, but it produces the same result. I think there's an issue in the ODBC driver that the Apache Ignite folks have to fix. I also tried inserting data for every data type, and trying to get the same data back, and I've noticed that the char, varchar, uuid, and date datatypes are not working correctly. For instance, when I insert data into a UUID column, I get back an object whose  datatype is really a byte[], and I have to convert it to a string myself, with something like (new System.IO.StreamReader(new System.IO.MemoryStream((byte[])value))).ReadToEnd().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug with Apache Ignite 2.7.0, so there is no answer. An issue has been filed with Apache Ignite to fix it.

http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-11845