# Why does PS5 add null characters to log file whilst PS7 does not?

Tags: powershell

I wrote a script that works perfectly in both PS7 and PS5, except it writes the log entries with null spaces after every character in PS5. I've never seen this before and can't find much about it online.

code that creates a log entry:

```
Write-Output "$logDate $thisScriptName v$thisScriptVersion - Script Started" | Out-File $logHistory -Append
```

The log file (open in VSCode):
[null character insertion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9ORX.png)

I can't copy and paste the text from VSCode (hence the snip) as it just pastes a null (0) value into the text area.

The correctly formatted text is added with ps7.

EDIT:
As per comments, this was fixed by adding -Encoding ascii (or utf8) to the Out-File. Using Add-Content -Value $string -Path $file also worked for me.

Comment: Seems to be an encoding problem utf-8 vs utf-16? Try `Out-File -Encoding utf8`

Comment: Could you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806305/powershell-2-0-generates-nulls-between-characters) and your files' encoding?

Comment: Quite right - thanks. I tried using Add-Content instead of piping to Out-File which worked without any problems. Changing the encoding also stops the issue. Appreciated!

Comment: out-file -append is positively dangerous, and can mix encodings in the same file.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr**

- `Out-File -Append` always uses a *default* character encoding, irrespective of the encoding of the existing content of the target file; in *Windows PowerShell*, this default is "Unicode" (UTF-16LE), which explains the unexpected `NUL` characters. Therefore, use the `-Encoding` parameter to match the character encoding of the existing content; e.g.:

  ```bash
  "$logDate $thisScriptName v$thisScriptVersion - Script Started" |
    Out-File -Encoding utf8 $logHistory -Append
  ```
- By contrast, `Add-Content` tries to *match* the existing content's encoding, but Windows PowerShell and PowerShell (Core) make *different* assumptions with respect to what the existing encoding is *if the existing file lacks a Unicode [BOM (byte-order mark)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)*:

  - Windows PowerShell, assumes *ANSI* encoding, whereas PowerShell (Core) assumes *UTF-8*. The only case in which this difference does *not* matter is if both the existing file content and the new content being added are composed of ASCII-range characters only.
  - Therefore, in *cross-edition* code you may need `-Encoding` even with `Add-Content`.

---

##### Background information:

In ***Windows PowerShell*** (the legacy, Windows-only, ships-with-Windows edition whose latest and *last* version is 5.1):

- **[`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file)'s default encoding - *whether or not you use `-Append`* - is "Unicode", i.e. UTF-16LE**, in which ASCII-range Unicode characters have a `NUL` (`0x`) byte as the high byte of each two-byte sequence encoding such a character, which is what you saw. This **also applies to the [redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection) operators, `>` and `>>`**, which are in effect aliases of `Out-File` and `Out-File -Append`

  - Therefore, if you use `Out-File -Append` with an existing file that uses an encoding *other* than UTF-16LE, you must **use the `-Encoding` parameter explicitly**, e.g.,
    `... | Out-File -Encoding utf8 -Append  $logHistory`
- By contrast, **[`Add-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/add-content)** and **[`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content)**, default to the **system's active ANSI code page**, as determined by the legacy system locale (aka language for non-Unicode programs), such as [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) on US-English systems.

  - However, unlike its conceptual analog, `Out-File -Append`, **`Add-Content` *tries to match the file's existing encoding*** based on the presence of a Unicode BOM. If there is none, the *ANSI* default applies.
    Notably, this means that a *BOM-less* UTF-8 will not be correctly appended to, and you'll need `-Encoding utf8` in that case too.

That different cmdlets in Windows PowerShell have *different defaults* is unfortunate - see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40098904/45375) for an overview.

Fortunately, this inconsistent use of character encodings has been rectified in *PowerShell (Core) 7+* - see below.

---

In **[*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)** (the modern, cross-platform, install-on-demand edition):

- Fortunately, the ***consistent* default** is **now (BOM-less) UTF-8** - this applies across all cmdlets and also to how the PowerShell engine itself reads source-code files.

  - Notably, this means that ANSI-encoded source-code files will be *misread* by PowerShell (Core) if non-ASCII characters are present, and the safe cross-edition way to save source-code files is to use UTF-8 *with BOM*.
- The **fundamental behaviors of `Out-File -Append` and `Add-Content` still apply**, however, which means:

  - Using `Out-File -Append` *without* `-Encoding` *always* appends UTF-8-encoded text.
  - Using `Add-Content` *without* `-Encoding` appends UTF-8-encoded text if the existing file has *no BOM*.
  - Notably, this means that an ANSI-encoded file (which *never* has a BOM)  will have incorrectly encoded text appended to it and requires use of
    `-Encoding ([cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ANSICodePage)`

    - Surprisingly, the `-Encoding` parameter does *not* accept `Ansi` as an identifier as of PowerShell 7.3.3, though this will likely be rectified in PowerShell 7.4 - see [GitHub PR #19298](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/pull/19298)